# Use contents of copy-paste buffer in command

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I would like to use the content that reside in the current copy-paste buffer in a Vim command.

For example:

```
nnoremap <leader>hi <cmd>echo "copy-paste-buffer-content"<CR>
```

Where this should print whatever was just yanked.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "copy-paste buffer" in Vim. See `help registers`.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase, how do I denote whatever register that yank produces, so I can echo it's content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
nnoremap <leader>hi <cmd>echo @"<CR>
```

Vim puts the content of was last been yanked into the `"` register.
You can access the `"` register using the variable `@"`.

Comment: Perfect thanks!